# What does the line @@ -9,9 +9,10 @@ mean in a diff file?

Tags: diff

Can someone please explain the third line in the sample `diff` output below (i.e., the one that starts with @@)?  I understand the changes represented by the remaining lines but am having trouble making sense of that third line...

```
--- a/code/c-skeleton/Makefile
+++ b/code/c-skeleton/Makefile
@@ -9,9 +9,10 @@
 TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
 TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@@ -9,9 +9,10 @@
```

...specifies where in the source and destination files changes take place, by line number and size of the chunk being edited, both before and after the changes.

Specifically:

```
@@ -9,9 +9,10 @@
^  ^^ ^ ^^ ^
|  || | || \----- The "10" is the number of lines in the hunk after being
|  || | ||        modified; this patch, then, must add a line, since the
|  || | ||        new count (of 10) is longer than the old count (of 9).
|  || | |\------- This "9" is the line number in the new file where the
|  || | |         modified hunk is placed.
|  || | \-------- This "+" is a hint that the following numbers refer to
|  || |           the new file, after modification.
|  || \---------- This "9" is the number of lines in the hunk before being
|  ||             modified.
|  |\------------ This "9" is the line number in the original file.
|  \------------- This "-" is a hint that the following numbers refer to the
|                 original file.
\---------------- This "@@" is a marker indicating that this is the start of a
                  new hunk.
```

That is to say: in the original file, the hunk being modified consists of 9 lines starting at line 9; in the destination file, it's 10 lines starting at line 9.

See the [detailed description of unified diff format](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified) in the GNU diffutils documentation.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome.  And I appreciate the link to the GNU documentation.  I'm going through an introductory C book at the moment and, in this particular chapter, the author referenced a diff file with little context as to various diff file formats; my google searching largely turned up pages on `patch vs. diff` which was unhelpful...hence the elementary question from me...  But the diagram makes it very clear!